# Unchecked Cast warnning and ClassCastException

Tags: android, kotlin, searchview

I have following code inside `publishResults` method where the containing adapter class implement `Filterable` interface to filter list of items.
(objective: filtering items in a recycler view using a search view)

```
override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
  // taskList is of type MutableList<TaskItem>  
  taskList.clear()

  // crash on
  taskList.addAll(results!!.values as Collection<TaskItem>)

  notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

app crashes with following error when tapped on search icon

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Filter$FilterResults cannot be cast to java.util.Collection
```

AS also shows following warning

```
Unchecked cast: Any! to Collection<TaskItem>
```

**How to convert the taskList to a Collection without casting?**

---

**Update**:

Added `performFiltering` method as @Andrei requested

```
override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {

            val filteredList = ArrayList<TaskItem>()

            if(constraint == null || constraint.isEmpty()){
                filteredList.addAll(duplicatedTaskList)
            }
            else{
                val filterPattern: String = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim()

                for (taskItem in duplicatedTaskList){
                    if(taskItem.title.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern))
                        filteredList.addAll(duplicatedTaskList)

                }
            }
            val filterResults = FilterResults()
            filterResults.values = filterResults

            return filterResults
        }
```

Comment: could you also attach your `performFiltering` method?

Comment: thanks for reaching out. added the method requested

Comment: @AndreiTanana Did you see any reason to down vote, did I violate any rules? I mean not you here okay. sometimes cannot understand folks here

Comment: from my point of view, there is no rules violation or something like that. But I'm not a rules guru anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `performFiltering` method should be

```
filterResults.values = filteredList
```

instead of

```
filterResults.values = filterResults
```

Then your code with casting will works

Comment: no crashing, warning is there though, I could just suppress. someother problems start popping up. let me get back to you guys later

Comment: @user158 in order for the lint error to disappear you need to use the code I gave you, it is not safe to iterate without checking if the object is the same type as the object you cast to

Answer (score 1):

I would loop on results!!.values with a for loop and check if the item is TaskItem.
making this if statement is safer than using as (casting) because it can cause unchecked cast error.

```
for (item in results!!.values) { 
  if(item is TaskItem) {
    taskList.add(item)
  } else {
      // Item is not task item, handle it 
  }
}
```

**Edit**

```
for (i in 0 until results!!.values.size) { 
  if(results!!.values.get(i) is TaskItem) {
    taskList.add(item)
  } else {
      // Item is not task item, handle it 
  }
}
```

Also try using:

```
filterResults.values = filteredList
```

Comment: there is error in for loop statement. not having an iterator()

Comment: sorry mate there is not size property in `results!!.values`

Comment: reason is because results is of type `FilterResults` which just an object which extends Object

Comment: Alright, anyways in order to prevent unchecked cast just check if your item is as task item

Comment: thank you for the information. I am going to use Fast Adapter, so much work for the adapter

Answer (score 1):

using `results!!.values as Collection<TaskItem>` will give you an exception if `results` is null, consider instead using the nullability operator (`results?.values`) instead.

maybe try something like this instead :

```
val list = results?.values as? Collection<*>

list?.let{
//here, you can use `it` to check if your list is not null
}
```

Comment: you need ? after result also since it can be null

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution that I use ( although I don't know if it is recommended or not)
is to use the same list in `performFiltering()` and `publishResults()` methods.

```
 taskList.addAll(filteredList); 
//Define filteredList outside as global variable
```

I don't see any reason of first adding items to `filteredList` inside `performFiltering()` method and then setting `filteredResults.value` to the same list and then in `publishResults()` method trying to get the same list back. Defining a global variable list seems better option.